# Windows 7 permissions on restored files

Tags: windows-7, permissions, filesystems

I restored an old Vista C: drive backup image to a new disk under Windows 7.  How do I set permissions so I can browse files and directories, and delete at will on the added drive?  Whenever I try to add full control privileges I get an "access denied" error for each object in the directory tree.

Comment: Do you plan on booting from this Vista disk?

Answer (score 1):

First, take ownership of all files on the new disk. Run from elevated Command Prompt:

```
takeown /r /f <path>
```

Replace `<path>` with the actual path to your files (for example, `C:\`)

Comment: might be dangerous if they plan on booting from this disk.

Comment: @Moab:  Did you forget to include a "coffee and cats" (humour) warning?  ;-D

Comment: They can find out the hard way I suppose, I did.